# Java compare array element to variable

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Brand new to Java, I am in the process of writing a program that has an array of numbers initialized, as well as a variable `B` that is holding a single integer. What I am trying to do is have my program compare the array elements to `B` and then print the array without the number `B`. Here is an example of what I currently have written up.

I want the array to be printed without the 17. Stuck on what to do after what I have written.

```
public class Harrison7b
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int[]arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};


      for(int B = 17; B < arrayA.length - 1; B++)
      {


      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to remove 17 in your array???

Comment: 1/ create a new array `arrayB` 2/ iterate over `arrayA` 3/ copy from `arrayA` into `arrayB` if num from `arrayA` is not 17 ? Some potential reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: start with B = 0 ; ??

Comment: I want the variable to compare to the array and since the variable is 17 and the array has 17 in it I would like it to print out the array with 17 removed

Comment: Looks like you need to reread the chapter on how `for` loop works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate counter variable to iterate through `Array` i,e; `i` and for checking whether your number is present in array or not you have to use `if statement`.

```
public class Harrison7b{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int B = 17;
        int[] arrayA = { 2, 4, 8, 19, 32, 17, 17, 18, 25, 17 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
            if (arrayA[i] != B) {
                System.out.print(arrayA[i]);
                System.out.print(i<arrayA.length-1? " ":"");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Harrison7b
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int[]arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};


      for(int B = 17; B < arrayA.length - 1; B++)
      {

for (int i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++)
if(arrayA[i]==B)
System.out.println(B);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a separate counter variable for iterate through the array or just use foreach loop as @DM mentioned. Let's use a counter, say `i`. Then you need to check whether the integer is in the array. Let's use an `if` condition for that.

Then your  code will be look like this:

```
public class Harrison7b
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int[]arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};


      int B = 17;

      for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
      // Or you may use just for(int x:arryaA)
      {
          if (arrayA[i] != B)
              System.out.println(arrayA[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick:  "You need a separate counter variable for iterate through the array." - No, not really.  `for (int x:myArray)` will work just fine.

Comment: @DM Yeah. That's true.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Harrison7b
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int[] arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};

      int num=17;

      for(int B = 0; B < arrayA.length; B++)
      {
          if(arrayA[B] == num){
              continue;
          }

          System.out.println(arrayA[B]);


      }
   }
}
```

You should start the loop from 0 index upto the length or array. In each iteration, compare the number with the current element of array. If they match, `continue` with the next iteration so that the number does not get printed.

This is a very simple program and I suggest you to spend time on thinking before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int[]arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};
    int myVar = 17;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
        if (arrayA[i] != myVar){
            System.out.print(arrayA[i]);
        }
    }
```

This will print out numbers that are not same with `17 //myVar`.

Comment: like this answer very simple for me to understand since I am a beginner, two questions as well for you. If i wanted to do this using a method call would that be possible? Also how would I separate the numbers on the array so they aren't so bunched up?

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 8 streams with [`filter`](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17};
        int valueToRemove = 17;

        // create a new array
        int[] newArray = Arrays.stream(
            myArray
        ).filter( // keep the values that aren't the value to remove
            value -> value != valueToRemove
        ).toArray();

        // print out the array
        for (int i : newArray) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```